# Procedure is exited upon marshalling a C struct received via WM_COPYDATA into a C# struct

Tags: c#, c, struct, marshalling, wm-copydata

Here is my problem. I am trying to Marshal a C struct into a C# struct. The C struct is sent from a C application to a C# application via a WM_COPYDATA message. Sending and acknowledging the message is not a problem and works perfectly fine.

I run the C application in debug, attach another debugger to the C# application and send the message. it is received and identified correctly but when I try to marshal the data, the Marshal.PtrToStructure function seems to exit the switch statement before executing the rest of it (see marked line in code).

The procedure `manageComplexMessage` is therefore not executed and the data remains raw and unusable.

This is the CopyDataStruct I use in C# :

```
private struct CopyDataStruct
{ 
    public IntPtr dwData; 
    public int cbData; 
    public IntPtr lpData; 
}
```

This is the struct I use in C# to store the data sent through WM_COPYDATA :

```
private struct ComplexData
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 75)]
    public int[] integers;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 75)]
    public double[] doubles;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 25)]
    public string[] strings;
};
```

The method that processes the WM_COPYDATA message :

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    int id;

    base.WndProc(ref m);

    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_COPYDATA:
            CopyDataStruct rawData = (CopyDataStruct) Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(CopyDataStruct)); // This Call to PtrToStructure works perfectly fine.
            id = rawData.dwData.ToInt32();

            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ComplexMessageId), id))
            {
                ComplexData data = (ComplexData) Marshal.PtrToStructure(rawData.lpData, typeof(ComplexData)); // This call makes the procedure exit.
                manageComplexMessage((ComplexMessageId) id, data);
                m.Result = (IntPtr) 1;
            }
            else
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr) 2;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The struct I use in C to send the data to my C# application :

```
struct ComplexData {    
    int Integers[75]; // Maximum 75 integers
    double Doubles[75]; // Maximum 75 doubles
    char Strings[25][256]; // Maximum 25 strings of a maximum length of 256 characters
};
```

And, finally, the procedure which sends the message :

```
int SendCopydataMessage(int MessageID, struct ComplexData MessageData)
{
    COPYDATASTRUCT DataToSend;

    int result;

    DataToSend.dwData = MessageID;
    DataToSend.cbData = sizeof(MessageData);
    DataToSend.lpData = &MessageData;

    if(WindowHandle != NULL) 
    {
        result = SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM) ((HWND) ExecWnd), (LPARAM) ((PVOID) &DataToSend));
        if(!result) 
        {
            return MESSAGENOTPROCESSED;
        }
        if(result == 2)
        {
            return UNDEFINEDMESSAGEID;
        }
    }

    return OK;
}
```

I suspect a problem when I Marshal the array of Strings but I can't find the problem.

Thank you all for your help! I hope someone can tell me what's wrong or point me toward the right direction!

**EDIT :** After more testing, the integer part and the double part of the struct works perfectly fine. Also if I send a single String it works. It only crashes when I try to send an array of String. The problem is then in my MarshalAs statement for the string array, but I still can't find out how to write properly.

Comment: The string array could be represented as `char[256 * 25]`.

Comment: This would work I guess yeah. Might do that if I don't find anything else thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indomitable beast: a 2d char array, inside a structure, in the belly of an unmanaged dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571907/indomitable-beast-a-2d-char-array-inside-a-structure-in-the-belly-of-an-unman)